# Clipping two layers to get contours underneath one layer

Tags: qgis, clip

I have a contour layer and another of the area I want to trim the contours down too.  I have them in the same CRS and i've tried intersection and clip under geoprocessing.  I can't seem to get any output from these tools. The clue is the boundary I want and the purple is what I want trimmed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reprojected the CRS of my shapefiles to a new CRS and then save-as with the new CRS set.  I brought them back in, clipped them, and then reprojected them again.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Please mark your answer as correct if it solved you're problem. Then the question will be removed from the unanswered feed.

Comment: @RopeyMaps I cannot mark my own answer as correct for two days